# Create new datatable for each element in a datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would try to do something like this

[image: tab1]

When I select an element in the category,the other `DataGridView` display the element linked to that category in this way.:
[image: tab2]

and when you add a new element in category,create a new empty data set link to the new element.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is master-detail relationship between two tables. To achieve this you need to:

1. Create DataSet object.
2. Add two tables to this DataSet - Master and Detail.
3. Load data into these tables.
4. Add appropriate DataRelation to DataSet
5. Create BindingSource for each of the grids.
6. Assing rescpective BindingSources to grids.
7. For master BindingSource set DataSource to be DataSet object and DataMember to be master table.
8. For detail BindingSource set DataSource to be master BindingSource and DataMember to be DataRelation created in 4th step.

I have used this approach to create multiple master-detail relations between grids and it works fine.

You can see more in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbwcse3d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).